# PhantomJS: view dependents such as .js, not just final html

Tags: phantomjs

In PhantomJS, is there a way to view the dependents? For example, a page causes a JS script to load. Instead of just viewing the final browser html result, I'd like to see the js script.

What I want to see has Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

In phantomjs you have the whole list of [page callbacks](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/).

Hooking to onResourceRequested and onResourceReceived will give you the desired information every time page tries to load anything.